# How to copy select cells in column from Excel speadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy-paste, microsoft-excel-2013

When I select specific cells within a column, Excel ends up copying the entire range of cells instead of just the ones I selected. I am using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>LEFT MOUSE ClICK</kbd> to select the cells. How do I copy the data just from the selected cells.

Comment: I don't experience this at all. I ctrl clicked on cellA1, cellA5 and cellA22 and the 3 cells were copied. Are you missing information in your post. Are these cells random? Are they part of a data table? Do you have any functions. How are you copying?

Comment: Doesn't happen with me. I select A1 then A10 (using CTRL + Click) and all cells in between are copied.

Comment: This indicates I must have a setting checked...

Comment: Indeed, because it seem foolish not to be able to copy only those cells selected.

Comment: This should work no problem assuming your noncontiguous selections are either in the **same row** or the **same column**. What it won't do is place the noncontiguous cells into noncontiguous cells. Or, if you're using formula or table references.

Comment: I agree ... this SHOULD work. But it doesn't. I am selecting values from the same column using CTRL + Click.

Comment: If you copy the first and last item in a column in the way you describe, and then paste as a picture it will copy the entire column. I assume it's not a picture when you paste?

Comment: Correct .. when I select the first cell in the column and then CTRL + Click the last cell in the column, copy and then paste into notepad, ALL cells in between are pasted in addition to the starting and ending cell. It is copying the range and I don't understand why.

Comment: Can you just copy the first item in the column and one mid way down (so only 2) and confirm if the same issue persists or not

Comment: I have confirmed this. If I select cell A1 and then CTRL + Click cell A15. Select copy .. then paste ... fifteen (15) values are pasted rather than the two (2) I would expect.

Comment: How many colums are in that row?

Comment: 10 columns in the row but I am not sure how that matters as I om only selected a single cell.

Comment: wait, are you pasting into notepad?  Into another excel instance?  Or into the same excel workbook?

Comment: Pasting into notepad.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible the way you try it. You can use the Clipboard, copy several fields/ranges one after the other and then paste them all in at once.

There are Addins that provide that feature though. In the source below Kutools is mentioned.

source: http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/799-excel-copy-multiple-selections.html

Answer (score 1):

I have a possible answer for you, but this solution only works if you are pasting directly into another (or the same) excel sheet. When pasting the selected values, right click where you wish to paste the values and select "Paste Special > Values".

Not only does this only paste the selected cells without the "in-betweens", it also removes blanks and compressses the selection without spaces.

I would suggest doing this and then moving it to whatever other document you might be using.

Answer (score 0):

Your cells are locked - thats what happened to me. Under format cells, go under the protection tab and make sure the 'Locked' box is NOT ticked. That should solve it.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Still getting the extra rows added in

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure the workbook is in Editable mode.  If you loaded it directly from an email attachment or it's not "Trusted" and it opens in read only mode, then it will behave like this.  When you multi-select cells/rows/columns it will include the unselected columns in between those selected when you cut or copy.  If the workbook is editable (not in read only mode) then it will behave as you intend and only cut/copy the selected cells.